# SEO Language information

Tags: html, seo

I was wondering if defining your language in HTML is better for search enigines. For example, I've got a French site, then i've got three options:

1.) have faith that google can say my site is french

2.) define language in the HTML tag

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr">
```

3.) define language in a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="FR-fr" />
```

Which option you believe is best? Or which combination of options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the lang attribute and the <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US">  tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436541/whats-the-difference-between-the-lang-attribute-and-the-meta-http-equiv-conten)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

language (language (i.e.: french) != location market (i.e. france)) detection is done on a per page basis (not per site).

it detects the language via the words used on the page (and in the URL), it does not care about the HTML tag (1) and the meta tag (2).

(you can test via the language detect api what language google thinks your page is using http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_langdetect.html )

i always go for the 1 page === 1 language approche. i always make sure that i only have one language per page (translating all of the navigation, making sure that other language content does not and can not show up on the page)

Comment: Do you mean one language for one specific URL?
For example 
a product page in English - [example.com/en/products](http://example.com/en/products)
and a product page in German -[example.com/de/products](http://example.com/de/products)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to define anything you can and have the search engine disregard it, than to not and leave it completely up to chance. The more information you give them the better.

Comment: perhaps for a variety of reasons not related to language? - most search engines rank on the content's context rather than meta information, so why would the language matter as long as the content is relevant to the topic being searched?

Comment: yeah you could do "define anything you can and have the search engine disregard it" but this also means that you do not know what action caused what effect. plus you just end up with more and more work (maintenance, quality assurance). i strongly believe that the less work (and code) you produce the better.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I stick with the 3rd one, the `content-language` meta tag, [as described here](http://www.seoconsultants.com/meta-tags/language).

Comment: funny ey, the site you refer to doesn't use it itself?

Comment: Never practice what you preach ;-)

Comment: ok, if we talk about google, forget it. it does not matter. the issue is that too many WYSIWYG editors prefill that argument with "en" so that it is not a reliable source. you can test this quite easily, just change all the content-language meta tags of your best performing site (or remove it alltogether) ... nothing happens. said that, i think bing has a blogpost that they take it into consideration (but hey, who cares about bing...)

Answer (score 0):

probabay should  be on webmasters.stackexchange.com but anyways

You should combine 2 and 3. Faith does not work with bots/spiders.

2.) define language in the HTML tag

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr">
```

3.) define language in a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="FR-fr" />
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

On top of defining your language in the html you can signup for the Google Webmaster tools. On that site you can set your geographic target to France (Site configuration -> Settings).

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

Comment: geographic target sets the target market (france) not the language (french)

Answer (score -1):

andrewk is right - use 2 or 3 , but take into account that in most cases the language will be detected by the robot it self automatically.