# Specifying webpage language

Tags: html

how can I specify the language of my website in HTML? I read that you can either use a meta tag or specify inside the `<html>` tag, which one is better?
If there is any other way, please specify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the lang attribute and the <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US"> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436541/whats-the-difference-between-the-lang-attribute-and-the-meta-http-equiv-conte)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the **[`lang=`](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)** attribute on the `<html>` element.

Comment: @JaceLee: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436541/whats-the-difference-between-the-lang-attribute-and-the-meta-http-equiv-conte

Comment: So let me get this straight, the `lang=` in the `<html>` is to say what language the page is written in, the `<meta>` is for saying what the language is going to be output as?

Comment: Nevermind that, seems that the `meta` is obsolete, so I'll use `<hrml lang="en">` for now, until something goes wrong. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using the tag, is it possible to add a line of code into the .htaccess file for that?